# Smooth change from headset_head_unit to and from a2dp_sink with a script

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero

I want to use my bluetooth bathroom speaker. That is connected to a pi zero 2  snapcast client. to pickup phone calls when im there.

I'm stuck at the point that i cant make a sollid cli script to change between headset_head_unit and a2dp_sink.
When i use the GUI all goes fine and i hear a reconnect on the speaker.
but when i use commandline tools.

```
$ pacmd set-card-profile 0 a2dp_sink
$ pacmd set-card-profile 0 headset_head_unit
```

the connection is not stable. I dont hear a reconnection from the speaker.
what is the diffrence?